# What does this error mean with 5d?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, haproxy

I have a web server with HAproxy for load balancing and two nginx+php-fpm.
When I opened my site I saw this error. I know what does  504 error mean, but why there are 5d?

[image: What does 5d mean ?]

Comment: You have a few tabs open.

Comment: I had 318 opened tabs ! And what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like something ignored or stripped out `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` from the response. That clearly looks like a [chunked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) response, but delivered to the browser unchunked.

Look for something between you and the web server that might be altering your connections in flight, such as another proxy server, firewall, state censorship regime, etc.

Comment: I know this error, but I need to know why here is 5d?

Comment: @GaniRakhmatov Because there were 93 (0x5d) bytes in the first chunk.

Comment: Could you specify your answer please?

Comment: What else do you want to know?

Comment: I mean transfering process

Comment: I read your link about chunks, thanks. So, this doesn't mean that my site has been hacked yeah ?

Comment: @GaniRakhmatov Your site probably isn't hacked, but _something_ is broken somewhere. You will need to go looking for it.

Comment: Figure out the actual source of the contents of the error message, to identify the error's source.  If the error is being *generated* by HAProxy, it's doubly strange, because HAProxy will *never* use chunked transfer encoding for errors it autonomously returns.  HAProxy error messages are acually created in memory buffers at server startup as an HTTP/1.0 response, with static-everything (including headers), and HAProxy just copies that buffer to the socket when the error occurs.  An HAProxy misconfiguration could be stripping or mangling upstream headers, if the error is from upstream.